# FFmpeg - filter-chaining and mapping output

Tags: ffmpeg

In FFmpeg, is it possible to map an output from the middle of a filter chain?

For example, in this command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i smptehdbars=rate=25:size=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50[txt1];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50[txt2];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50[txt3];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50[txt4]" -map "[txt4]" -t 10 -y ~/Desktop/mapping.mp4
```

This works: -map "[txt4]". When trying to -map "[txt3]" (or txt2, or txt1) I get "

> Output with label 'txt3' does not exist in any defined filter graph,
> or was already used elsewhere."

I want to call the full command and and use different parts of the filter chain (`-map [$val]`) to output different files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but we have to use [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit) filter for the "middle filter".

When the "middle filter" is used as input to other filter it is "consumed" by that filter, and cannot be used later.

---

Here is an example for creating video files from all the "middle filters" with one command:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i smptehdbars=rate=25:size=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt1][txt1out];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt2][txt2out];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt3][txt3out];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf[txt4]" -t 10 -map "[txt1out]" mapping1.mp4 -t 10 -map "[txt2out]" mapping2.mp4 -t 10 -map "[txt3out]" mapping3.mp4 -t 10 -map "[txt4]" mapping4.mp4`

---

For encoding each files separately, we may add [streamselect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#streamselect_002c-astreamselect) filter, at the end of the filters chain:

`[txt1out][txt2out][txt3out][txt4]streamselect=4:map=1[out]`

Set `map=0` for selecting `[txt1out]`, set `map=1` for selecting `[txt2out]`...

Sample command:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i smptehdbars=rate=25:size=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt1][txt1out];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt2][txt2out];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf,split[txt3][txt3out];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50:fontfile=arial.ttf[txt4];[txt1out][txt2out][txt3out][txt4]streamselect=4:map=1[out]" -t 10 -map "[out]" mapping2.mp4`

---

Note:
Adding `fontfile=arial.ttf` was required for making `drawtext` to work in Windows.

Comment: Split filter will allow to map video from the middle of the chain but still, the other outputs must be used.
I was looking for a way to encode files separately, each time with a different part of the chain.

Comment: You may use  `streamselect` filter. I updated my answer.